# DLL Injection does not work twice

Tags: dll, dll-injection, thread, process

I created a program that performs DLL injection. It does that by opening the process with `OpenProcess`, writes the DLL path to the process and creates a remote thread with `CreateRemoteThread` with the dll as a parameter.(The DLL just spawns a messagebox). It works just fine but the problem is the second time i can't see the messagebox. The functions `OpenProcess`, `CreateRemoteThread`, `VirtualAllocEx`, `WriteProcessMemory` all return true but i can't see the thread being created and the DLL does not run.

Thanks.

Comment: second time during the same run or another one?

Comment: second time i try to inject the same dll to the same process, the dll does not run @IgorSkochinsky

Comment: are you  calling `LoadLibrary` in the injected thread?

Comment: yes i get a handle to the LoadLibrary function and pass it as a parameter to the CreateRemoteThread @IgorSkochinsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `LoadLibrary` twice with the same DLL name only increases the load counter but does not cause DLL entrypoint to be called again. From [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175) (emphasis mine):

> If the specified module is a DLL that is **not already loaded** for the
>   calling process, the system calls the DLL's DllMain function with the
>   DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value. If DllMain returns TRUE, LoadLibrary returns
>   a handle to the module. If DllMain returns FALSE, the system unloads
>   the DLL from the process address space and LoadLibrary returns NULL.
>   It is not safe to call LoadLibrary from DllMain. For more information,
>   see the Remarks section in DllMain.

So if you need to execute your code again you'll have to do it explicitly, `LoadLibrary` won't do it for you.

**EDIT:**

One possible solution could be to use the address of the function in your (already loaded) DLL instead of `LoadLibrary` as the address of the second dinjected thread.

Comment: I am sorry but i did not understand how exactly i am going to do it explicitly. This is the code: `remote_dll_path= (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, &RemoteAddress, size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE); WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, remote_dll_path, full_dll_path, size, NULL); hKernel32 = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"); LoadLibraryAddress = GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryA"); CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryAddress, remote_dll_path, 0, &threadId); VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)remote_dll_path, size, MEM_DECOMMIT)`

Comment: you'll need to add some shellcode which would call the necessary function from the DLL. Just `LoadLibraryA` by itself is not enough if you need to run it twice.

Comment: also see my edit.